# How would I reference a python package for a pipeline script?

Tags: python, db2

I’m creating a script to be run as a part of a pipeline that will execute .sql files for ibm’s db2. I’m not so concerned with the reading of the .sql files and executing the commands as much as I am just getting my script to recognize the package from within the directory.

This is my current directory setup:

```
*ibm_db2-3.0.1 (the folder containing the ibm driver)  
|    |  
|    *ibm_db.py  
|    |  
|    *etc driver files  
|  
*__init__.py  
|  
*main.py  
|  
*table.sql
```

`import ibm_db` tells me `module not found` and I assumed it wouldn’t work since it’s not installed into the `PYTHONPATH`. It needs to be referenced locally to be run on whatever machine runs the script as part of the pipeline.

How might I get my python script to recognize the `ibm_db` package so the script can perform the sql commands where ever?

Comment: `__init__.py` must be in your `home` folder. Can you show your setup.py?

Comment: My setup.py has `import setuptools    setuptools.setup( name=‘ibm_db’, version’3.0.1’, install_requires=[], packages=setuptools.find_packages(),)`. Sorry about formatting, it’s weird on mobile

Answer (score 1):

You should have `__init__.py` in your home application folder and then you can create another dir in this folder (as ex. `dependencies`) where you store your `ibm_db.py` and other needed scripts.

You can then easily call it from scripts in your home folder with:

```
from dependencies.ibm_db import <function>
```

or if you need them all:

```
import dependencies.ibm_db
```

Comment: Okay, so because mobile is being difficult, I’ll just have to describe what I have. I have my folder called script, and within that I have `home(folder), __init__.py, main.py, setup.py, and test.sql`. Within my home folder, I have `__init__.py, dependencies (folder)`. Within dependencies, I have `ibm_db-3.0.1, __init__.py`, and within ibm_db-3.0.1 are the package files including `ibm_db.py`

Comment: Try replace "." and "-" with "_" in `ibm_db-3.0.1` folder name and then `form dependencies.ibm_db_3_0_1 import <a-function-to-test-it>` and test the function work from main. BTW: why do you have `__init__.py` both in home and dependencies folder too?